# Insert data into Hive table using lookup table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-query

Could someone help me in this scenario?

How to insert data into a Hive table by looking up values from other Hive table?

My input_source table is like below:

```
date    key  lines  type
29-May  1     A     A16
29-May  2     B     D44
29-May  3     C     K90
29-May  4     A     L90
29-May  5     A     J76
29-May  6     B     Y78
```

I have detailed description of each of the types above.
For example:

```
A and A16 is "Excellet"
B and D44 is "Average"
A and L90 is "Good"
B and Y78 is "Fair"
```

and so on..

During I insert the data into result table, I need to read the lines and type and insert the description in the final table as below:

```
date    key   desc
29-May  1     Excellent
29-May  2     Average
29-May  3     Not bad
29-may  4     Good
29-May  5     Fine
29-may  6     Fair
```

Could you please advice to achieve this?

Comment: where is the detailed description stored? is it a table?

Comment: Yes It is stored in a Hive table

Comment: Is the detailed description single column table?

Comment: No, the detailed description has 3 columns. lines,type,desc

Answer (score 0):

Use Join. Here is what is probably needed.

```
insert overwrite table target_table
select date,key,descrip
from 
(
select a.date,a.key,a.lines, a.type,b.descrip from 
input_source a 
join 
description_table b 
on a.lines = b.lines and a.type = b.type
)
t;
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I will let you know the result after trying your query. Thanks.